# Duda en la ejecución de un programa

Tags: python, numpy

Hola muy buenas a todos!!
Tengo una pequeña duda a la hora de ejecutar un programa. Mi duda es la siguiente:

Tengo el siguiente programa:

main.py

```
import dates
date = "01-06-1970"
result = dates.datestr2datetuple(date)
print(result)

dates.py
def datestr2datetuple(date):
    result = (date[:2], date[3:5], date[6:])
    return result
```

Cuando se ejecuta, se ve de la siguiente forma:

```
('01', '06', '1970')
```

Y quiero que se muestre de la siguiente forma y no sé como puedo mejorarlo

```
(01, 06, 1970)
```

Quiero que se imprima pero sin las comillas

Comment: En principio parece que bastaría convertir a entero cada elemento de la tupla que retornas, que actualmente es una cadena (y de ahi las comillas). No obstante, al pasar a entero desaparecerían los ceros por la izquierda. Es decir, el `'01'` se convierte en `1` y no en `01` como pides. Si esta solución no te vale, indícalo en un comentario, pues habría otra forma (ligeramente más compleja) de convertir la tupla de cadenas en una sola cadena, con el formato que pides.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Me ha sido de gran ayuda todos vuestros comentarios. Pero aparte de ese método de salida, necesito que se ejecute de las siguiente dos formaS: ('27-12-1808') → Corresponde a la primera forma (27-12-1808) → Corresponde a la segunda forma

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/178039)

Comment: Con las f-strings que te dije se puede hacer sin problemas estas dos formas. Además acuerdate de aceptar como válida la respuesta que más te valga.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar f-strings para formatear el código de manera más sencilla. Cambia tu linea de result por esta:

```
result = f"{date[:2]}, {date[3:5]}, {date[6:]}"
```

Las f-string son strings precedidas por la letra `f` y básicamente ejecutan variables dentro de los simbolos `{}`. Así que dar formato legible a diferentes variables en una misma string se vuelve sencillo. Ejemplo:

```
result = f"Día {date[:2]} del mes {date[3:5]} del año {date[6:]}"
```

Los resultados de esos dos ejemplos son:

01, 06, 1970
Día 01 del mes 06 del año 1970

**Edit:** Para las nuevas formas que necesitas:

```
result = f"({date[:2]}-{date[3:5]}-{date[6:]})"
```

(01-06-1970)

Answer (score 1):

Aunque en tu pregunta dices que quieres la salida en este formato:

```
(01, 06, 1970)
```

quizás te sirvan otros similares, de modo que te daré diferentes recetas.

La forma más simple de obtener exactamente la salida que pides, si `result` es el resultado que devuelve tu función `dates.datesr2datetuple()` sería:

```
print("({}, {}, {})".format(*result))  # Sale: (01, 06, 70)
```

El asterisco delante de `result` lo "desempaqueta", con lo que `format` recibe tres parámetros que usa para sustituir posicionalmente donde haya `{}` en la cadena.

Si no te importa que los 0 delante de los dígitos desaparezcan, puedes convertir a enteros los datos, mapeando la función `int` sobre cada elemento de tu `result` y convirtiendo de nuevo a `tuple` para que salga entre paréntesis y separado por comas.

```
print(tuple(map(int, result)))   # Sale:  (1, 6, 1970)
```

Si los paréntesis no son obligatorios en tu salida, y te sirve por ejemplo `01, 6, 1970` como resultado, puedes simplemente usar `join()` para concatenar los elementos de `result` usando una coma como separador. Esta solución, al usar las cadenas originalmente presentes en `result`, respeta los 0 delante de los dígitos.

```
print(", ".join(result))   # Sale: 01, 06, 1970
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que te devuelva exáctamente `(01,06,1970)`, como te dice abulafia en su comentario, no bastará con pasar cada elemento a tipo entero. Podrías hacerlo con el modulo datetime, aunque tu código cambiaría por completo:

```
from datetime import datetime

date = "01-06-1970"

fecha = datetime.strptime(date, '%d-%m-%Y')

print(fecha.strftime('(%d,%m,%Y)'))  #>> Devolvería (01,06,1970)
```

Pero en este caso lo que devuelve también sería tipo texto. La variable `fecha` sería tipo `datetime` que es con lo que se suele trabajar cuando se trata de fechas.